# New DataFrame with columns based on two conditions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with the following columns.

```
AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF  HH
```

I need to select all the rows that have the `"CT"` in column `BB` and sort by column `FF`.

For the life of my I can't figure out how to do this. 
It seems very simple but I'm missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

To select rows with `CT` you can use

```
df[ df['BB'] == 'CT' ]
```

or if it can be `CT` in longer string, ie. `CTX`

```
df[ df['BB'].str.contains('CT') ]
```

And then you can sort it using [sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)

```
.sort_values('FF')
```

Full example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'AA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'BB': ["", "CT", "", "CT", "CT", "", "", "CT"],
    'CC': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'DD': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'EE': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'FF': [0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 7],
    'HH': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

print(df[ df['BB'] == 'CT' ])
print(df[ df['BB'] == 'CT' ].sort_values('FF'))
```

Data at start

```
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF  HH
0   1       1   1   1   0   1
1   2  CT   2   2   2   1   2
2   3       3   3   3   0   3
3   4  CT   4   4   4   5   4
4   5  CT   5   5   5   2   5
5   6       6   6   6   0   6
6   7       7   7   7   0   7
7   8  CT   8   8   8   7   8
```

After `df[ df['BB'] == 'CT' ]`

```
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF  HH
1   2  CT   2   2   2   1   2
3   4  CT   4   4   4   5   4
4   5  CT   5   5   5   2   5
7   8  CT   8   8   8   7   8
```

After sorting

```
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  FF  HH
1   2  CT   2   2   2   1   2
4   5  CT   5   5   5   2   5
3   4  CT   4   4   4   5   4
7   8  CT   8   8   8   7   8
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df[df["BB"] == "CT"].sort_values(["FF"])
```